# Как получить ключ из firebase?

Tags: java

Как получить уникальный ключ при поиске по ФИО? Сам поиск работает, значение находится, нужно только вернуть ключик этого пользователя. Кто чем подскажет?

```
public void retriveKeyFromDB(View view) {
    String name = name_client_search.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
    Query query = mDataBase.orderByChild("name_client").equalTo(name);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(NewOrder.this, "есть", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(NewOrder.this, "нету", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно не дождался ответов, решил вопрос таким образом:
когда вызывается метод push() и создается уникальный ключ, мы заносим его в firebase в качестве значения:

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDataBase.push();
 String key = databaseReference.getKey();
```

Далее мы можем обращаться уже к полю key

```
 public void retriveKeyFromDB(View view) {
    String name = name_client_search.getText().toString();
    Query query = mDataBase.orderByChild("name_client").equalTo(name);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = ds.child("key").getValue(String.class);
                    name_client_search.setText(key);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(NewOrder.this, "увы и ах :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```